# Modify another program's WinAPI layout

Tags: windows, gui, wysiwyg

I have a program that displays a GUI overlay using raw WinAPI and I was wondering if anyone was aware of any tools that injects itself in another program and allows you to modify the GUI of the program in real time? For example, if I wanted to change the size of a button, I would use the tool to stretch the button.

A sort of real-time WYSIWYG for another program.

I am aware that I could write my own one that modifies UI attributes using code but it would save me a lot of time if there was a tool already out there for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like WinSpy++ ? http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17

Some other tools can be found here:
http://woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Window_Manipulation_Tools

for example, Window Hack, and MagicMouse/Customiser form www.wanga.com